# A determiner/determiners

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I remember back that day when I commented on someone's post that had a lot of missing determiners saying:

> You need determiners for the computer and the tv.

Since there should be more than one determiners, I wrote *determiners*. Now I think I was wrong: I think it should be *a determiner* because the sentence should be like the following one.

> You need a determiner for the computer and a determiner for the tv.

> You need a determiner for the computer and tv.

Should I say *determiners for* or *a determiner for* in the sentence I wrote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need determiners before the computer and the tv.

might be better phrased

> You need to use determiners *before* computer and tv.

since your original sentence includes the determiners.

"Determiners" is correct since there is a determiner for each, to say

> You need **a** determiner for...

would mean to use a single determiner, which might be correct if you are grouping "computers and tvs" together like "bacon and eggs"

> We looked at the computers and tvs at Walmart.
>   We had the bacon and eggs special for breakfast.

but you are saying **the** computer and **the** tv, determiners for each.